# Default value for non-existing variable

Tags: vba

I was working on a VBA excel-based project and made a typo while calling a variable. After trying to debug the function for a while, I realised I was making a reference to a non-existing variable (because of the typo) and yet the debugger didn't indicate the issue.

I tried to get the value of the variable and the result was empty. I tried to do a comparison with the variable and it was returning false every time.

I'd like to know if it has something to do with the `Boolean` default value which is `False` (as said by Microsoft for the VB language [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/boolean-data-type))? And if it's the case, why is it printing no value?

Also, why did the debugger indicate no issue?

```
Sub MySub()
    'Print absolutely nothing
    Debug.Print myVariable

    If (myVariable) Then
        Debug.Print "Condition is true"
    Else
        'The condition always comes in that
        Debug.Print "Condition is false"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you do not declare the variable, it is assumed to be variant and the natural state of a variant is Empty.

Actually the first line is printing a blank line in the Immediate window since it is empty.

When it is first used as you have VBA assumes you wanted to use it as Boolean and therefor it changes to a Boolean and the base or empty value of a boolean is False.

```
Sub MySub()

    Debug.Print myVariable 'Prints and empty line As the variable is Empty Variant

    If (myVariable) Then 'Treated as a Boolean with value False empty = false
        Debug.Print "Condition is true"
    Else
        'This fires as base boolean value is False
        Debug.Print "Condition is false"
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

If you want an error to pop up then use `Option Explicit` at the top of the module or set that as default in the settings.

To set it as the default go to `Tools` ==> `Options` and click `Require Variable Declaration`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well it's a very interesting answer, thank you very much!

Comment: The variable does not seems to become "boolean" after the test, it still is Variant/Empty (try put `Debug.Print Typename(myVariable)` in some places). But Empty variant are evaluated to false in test.

Comment: +10000 for `Option Explicit`. Another 10000 for adding in the VBE setting: `Tools | Options` then selecting `Require Variable Declaration` on the `Editor` tab. This will _automatically_ put `Option Explicit` in _every_ code module so you don't have to remember to do it by hand.

Comment: I'd suggest *turning off* `Auto Syntax Check` - when you write a line that is wrong it'll still color it red, but you won't get a popup telling you as much. (At least I found that popup utterly annoying.)

Comment: @Inarion while I agree with you, not a part of the scope of this question, So I did not address it, otherwise it would start to delve into opinion.

Comment: I see. Thought I'd mention it, as I find that setting's behavior to be a little counterintuitive. (Says it disables the check whereas it actually disables *only a part of the notification*.) And with everything regarding general VBA knowledge, I feel we have to always expect the worst (no knowledge) and hope for the best (person knows exactly what they are doing). :)

Comment: Shouldn't have `(myVariable)`, the parentheses are not necessary (and in some cases could result in unusual results)